# Persian Numbers Font Not Displaying Properly in Numbered Lists in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, numbering

I'm using Microsoft Word 2019, and I've encountered an issue where Persian numbers in numbered lists do not display correctly. Despite setting the numeral mode to "context" in Word Options, the numbers still appear in Latin fonts (e.g., Arial) instead of the selected Persian font.

In Word 2013, I didn't face this problem, but it seems to persist in Word 2016 and later versions.

Here are the steps I've tried:

Changing the default font to a Persian font in Word Options.
Manually changing the font for the numbered list to a Persian font.
Creating a new style for numbered lists with the Persian font.
Ensuring the document's language settings are set to Persian.
Checking for software updates and repairing the Office installation.
None of these steps have resolved the issue. I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to get Persian numbers to display correctly in numbered lists in Word 2019 and newer versions. As you seen in the following image, the numbers font do not match the text font.

Is there a specific setting or workaround I might be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB5oj.png)